# Using Logical Operators inside NULLIF()

Tags: sql, sql-server

If, then how can we use logical operators inside the NULLIF() funtion in SQL. Suppose i have a variable @a with value 5. I want to return NULL value if 
@a>3. (which it is)

```
DECLARE @a INT
SET @a = 5;

SELECT NUllIF(@a,>3) AS Logical
-- Error: Incorrect syntax near '>'.

SELECT NUllIF(@a,'>3') AS Logical
-- Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '>200' to data type int.
```

Comment: which sql language are you using

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I'm working on Microsoft SQL 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a INT
SET @a = 5;
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(@a,0)>3 THEN NULL ELSE @a END AS output
```

Was that what it was about?

Comment: I' m glad that I could help, have a nice day :) @KT11

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @a<=3 THEN @a END AS Logical
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
DECLARE @a AS INT = 5;
SELECT IIF(@a > 3, NULL, @a) AS Logical
```